# expected number, but returning string

Tags: javascript, string, function, numbers, javascript-objects

I am writing a basic function to complete exercism.io's Space Age(easy) activity. The function I've written returns the correct number but as a string, can someone please advise why?

I know this is probably a simple answer, but I'm lost even after running through the debugger tool and searching stack overflow questions.

Please don't provide a solution to the exercise , as I'd like to figure that out on my own.

I have read similar titled questions on stack overflow, such as:
[Number function returning string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38411991/number-function-returning-string)

```
var age = (planet, seconds) => {

    var orbitalPeriod;

    const solarsystem = {
        earth : 1,
        mercury : 0.2408467,
        venus : 0.61519726,
        mars : 1.8808158, 
        jupiter : 11.862615, 
        saturn : 29.447498, 
        uranus : 84.016846,
        neptune : 164.79132
    }
    orbitalPeriod = solarsystem[planet];

    return (seconds / 31557600 / orbitalPeriod).toFixed(2);
}

age('mercury',2134835688); 

// returns "280.88"
```

I have also tried using Number and parseFloat on the orbitalPeriod variable and return value like:

```
    orbitalPeriod = Number.parseFloat(solarsystem[planet]);

    return Number.parseFloat(seconds / 31557600 / orbitalPeriod).toFixed(2);
```

Comment: `toFixed` returns a string, that's it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have to use `parseFloat` for the entire output. as in your question you used 
`.toFixed(2)` which will return string. you need to add `parseFloat` for the entire result.

```js
var age = (planet, seconds) => {

    var orbitalPeriod;

    const solarsystem = {
        earth : 1,
        mercury : 0.2408467,
        venus : 0.61519726,
        mars : 1.8808158, 
        jupiter : 11.862615, 
        saturn : 29.447498, 
        uranus : 84.016846,
        neptune : 164.79132
    }
    orbitalPeriod = solarsystem[planet];

    return parseFloat((seconds / 31557600 / orbitalPeriod).toFixed(2));
}

var ageVal = age('mercury',2134835688);
console.log(ageVal, typeof(ageVal));
```

Comment: My guess is because OP says "*Please don't provide a solution to the exercise , as I'd like to figure that out on my own.*"

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I see, I was using the toFixed method incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

Use `parseFloat` after `toFixed`.

**Note:** There is not need to put `Number` before `parseInt` or `parseFloat` they are on `window` object.

```
return Number.parseFloat((seconds / 31557600 / orbitalPeriod).toFixed(2));
```

Or use Unary Plus `+`.

```
return +((seconds / 31557600 / orbitalPeriod).toFixed(2));
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, I gave an upvote for mentioning the unary plus method.